# mySQL group by function showing lack of data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join

What I'm after is to see what is the fastest lap time for particular races, which will be identified by using race name and race date.

```
SELECT lapName AS Name, lapDate AS Date, T
FROM Lap 
    INNER JOIN Race ON Lap.lapName = Race.Name
        AND Lap.lapDate = Race.Date
GROUP BY Date;
```

It currently only displays 3 different race names, with 4 different dates, meaning I've got 4 combinations total, when there are in fact 9 unique race name, race date combinations.

Unique race data is stored in the Race table. Laptimes are stored in the LapInfo table.

I'm also getting a warning about my group statement saying it is ambiguous though it still runs.

Comment: You need to use some sort of aggregation -- I assume `min(laptime)`...

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL allows bad SQL when it comes to grouping. As a rule of thumb, any column that is not in the `GROUP BY` needs to be aggregated, using `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc. Please do this to make sure we get your query.

Comment: And please indicate the tables each column belongs to. For example, instead of `raceDate` type `Race.raceDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to need a `join` for this:

```
SELECT l.lapRaceName, l.lapRaceDate, 
       MIN(l.lapTime)
FROM LapInfo l
GROUP BY l.lapRaceName, l.lapRaceDate;
```

If you don't need a `JOIN`, it is superfluous to put one in the query.

Comment: I believe I need an inner join to ensure null values are not considered?

Comment: @bemzoo . . . Just add `where lapracename is not null and lapracedate is not null`.  Presumably, the race names are valid names, so the inner join is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your query is actually invalid SQL. You need to use the `MIN` function to get the fastest `lapTime`. Also, you have to `GROUP BY lapRaceName, raceDate` instead of just `lapRaceName`. Unfortunately, in this case, mysql is lax enough to execute it without error.

Also, you JOIN `LapInfo` with `Race`, and return jthe joined columns from `LapInfo` that you alias as names that can be found in `Race`. That's OK from SQL point of view, but that's also usulessly complicated : return directly the columns from the `Race` table, as they have the names that you are looking for.

Finally, it would be far better to indicate which table each column belongs to. Here, column `lapTime` belongs to table `LapInfo`, so let's make it explicit.

Query :

```
SELECT 
    Race.raceName,
    Race.raceDate, 
    MIN(LapInfo.lapTime)
FROM 
    Race 
    INNER JOIN LapInfo
        ON  LapInfo.lapRaceName = Race.raceName
        AND LapInfo.lapRaceDate = Race.raceDate
GROUP BY 
    Race.raceName,
    Race.raceDate
;
```

Comment: Thank you, perhaps mySQL isn't best for learning syntax. Also you find slowest lap time rather than fastest.